How can I utilize non-default symbols in my glossary?
I'd like to insert an uppercase \Chi into my symbols glossary, but for some reason only the lowercase version works (a MWE is below). However, though an error is thrown, the document compiles on Overleaf and the symbol appears correctly in the glossary (in uppercase). Any ideas on how to resolve the error message would be greatly appreciated!
\documentclass{report}

% margins
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
% images
\usepackage{graphicx}
% math typesetting
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% add appendix to table of contents
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
% links
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
% create list of acronyms for appendix -- must be loaded *after* hyperref for links to work 
\usepackage[acronym, nopostdot, toc, section, numberedsection=autolabel, nogroupskip, symbols]{glossaries-extra}
\glsdisablehyper
\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
% format glossaries correctly based on width of longest term 
%\usepackage{glossary-tree}

% list of all symbols used for glossary
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Pearson's \ensuremath{\chi}-squared test statistic}]{chi-squared-test-stat}{\ensuremath{\Chi^2}}

% title & author definition
\title{Example Document}
\author{First Last}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter One}

Some example text. 

\appendix 

\chapter{Notation}

% align glossary entires correctly
\glsfindwidesttoplevelname
\setglossarystyle{alttree}
% prevent bold text from being printed in math section
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}
% print math symbols in second section
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols]

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX StackExchange! This is actually the expected behavior for TeX:  if an uppercase Greek letter and uppercase Latin letter have the same appearance, the command for the Greek won't exist, which will throw an error about an undefined command.

Unrelated to TeX, but why not just keep your glossary entry as lowercase with \chi^2? I think most readers (myself included) would be rather confused if we saw an uppercase Χ² for a variable that we normally write in lowercase. A non-representative sample of reference books from my shelf seems to suggest it's the norm to keep lowercase variables as lowercase in glossaries.

Well specifically the statistic as defined in most textbooks uses an uppercase \Chi to distinguish it from the Chi-squared distribution, which is denoted by the lowercase \chi.
